# What is the correct style parent definition

Tags: android, android-styles

When looking at the examples of defining style parent I noticed two different approaches are used for explicit parenting:

Number one:

```
<style name="MyButton" parent="android:Widget.Button"/>
```

Number two:

```
<style name="MyButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button"/>
```

As far as I could see, they both seem to work. I wonder if both of these approaches are correct or there is one I should stick to?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, but stick to this:

```
<style name="MyButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button"/>
```

As this accesses your current compileSdkVersion's resource directory.

Comment: Thanks, can you provide a source for that statement? I would really like to know the exact differences... why do some great programmers use the other method then (http://blog.danlew.net/2014/11/19/styles-on-android/)?

Comment: The official android example for styles(http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) uses the above mentioned way.